# Can someone explain this error when trying to create a custom tool?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to create a new tool following the steps in the nova documentation.
I try `php artisan nova:tool Tree` and i get the error `An option named "no-interaction" already exists.`
Google doesnt find anything. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Laravel Nova 3.7

Comment: I would like any ideas how to circumvent it